# Create an isometric map with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a small game with Javascript/HTML 5. For this game i need an isometric map where each square is clickable.

How can i make that? Do you know some plugins to help me to do that?

I find this solution http://www.cw-internetdienste.de/isomap/ but the result is not very good...

Thank you

Comment: i like craftyjs its light weight http://www.craftyjs.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Crafty.js](http://craftyjs.com/) is able to do clickable isometric maps.  There's even a [isometric sample](http://craftyjs.com/demos/isometric/) where you can right click on blocks to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [jgen](http://code.google.com/p/jgen/) and [pp3Diso](http://www.prelude-prod.fr/demo/pp3diso/).

Answer (score -7):

http://www.glacialflame.com/ have nice tutorial's how to implement isometric in HTML5 Canvas

Comment: Site is gone. This is why we don't post link only answers

Comment: The underlying isometric map "engine" for Glacial Flame can be found here https://github.com/beakable/isometric 
I suggest to check it out, it's very straightforward!